# Flutter App unable to access internet when in background

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, background-process

I am building a taxi app (Runs on both Android and IOS) that is required to update Driver location to the database after every 10 Seconds using a Timer.
Driver current location is being well picked continuously by the geolocator package then sent to the live database.

**Problem**
The updates only work well when the app is in foreground
As soon as the app is taken to background or minimized, I receive a "No Internet or Wifi" error and the location is therefore not updated.
The Timer continues to run in the background but due to the no internet, it fails to update the database.

**Question**
What can I do to ensure that the app receives internet while in background so that it continuously updates driver location?

**Timer**

```
Timer timer;
timer = Timer.periodic(Pallete.refreshTime, (timer) {
  _getLocation();
});
```

**_getLocation**

```
Future<void> _getLocation() async {
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).then((value) =>{
      postLocation( context,'${value.latitude},${value.longitude}')
    });
}

postLocation(BuildContext context,String location){
    final myCubit = BlocProvider.of<DriveractivejobCubit>(context);
    myCubit.updateLocation(context, location);
}
```

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60441628/14231239 ?

Comment: I think this helps, thanks. ...Do you propose I delete this question or how should I redirect people to that other link?

Answer (score 0):

A better explanation as to why this happens can be found on this link.
It also explains the few options we have to make this happen.
Thanks to @dm_tr
 [stackoverflow.com/a/60441628/14231239](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/60441628/14231239)